# Not receiving mail with "adminCreateUser" function in AWS Cognito

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to create User with `adminCreateUser` function, but I am not receiving temporary password on my mail id.

```
var RegisterUser = exports.RegisterUser = function (data) {
var params = {
            UserPoolId: __MY_POOL_ID__,
            Username: data.username, 
            DesiredDeliveryMediums: [
                  'EMAIL'
            ],
            ForceAliasCreation: false,
            MessageAction: 'SUPPRESS',
            TemporaryPassword: 'tempPassword1',
            UserAttributes: [
                  {
                        Name: 'email',
                        Value: data.email
                  },
                  {
                        Name: 'name', 
                        Value: data.name
                  }
            ]
      };
      return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            _CISP.adminCreateUser(params, function (err, data) {
                  if (err) {
                        rej(err)
                  }
                  else {
                        res(data)
                  }
            });
      })
}
```

- Case 1: When I am trying to creating a user from the Cognito AWS Console, then I am receiving the temporary password. (It is working)
- Case 2: When I am trying to create a user using Cognito Admin API, can not get password. (Not working) Any idea?

Comment: usefull nice question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove

```
MessageAction: 'SUPPRESS'
```

That option prevents messages from sending: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminCreateUser.html#CognitoUserPools-AdminCreateUser-request-MessageAction